# db2: configurations covered by "create db autoconfigure"

Tags: db2, memory, db2-luw, db2-10.5

I am new to configuring memory in db2. I want to create a database using this command:

`db2 CREATE DB TEST USING CODESET UTF-8 TERRITORY US AUTOCONFIGURE USING mem_percent 80 APPLY DB ONLY`

According to [IBM's Knowledge Center](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSEPGG_9.7.0/com.ibm.db2.luw.admin.config.doc/doc/t0005243.html):

> ...the **AUTOCONFIGURE** command which will generate values for parameters based on your responses to questions about workload characteristics.
>
> Some configuration parameters can be set to AUTOMATIC, allowing the database manager to automatically manage these parameters to reflect the current resource requirements. To turn off the AUTOMATIC setting of a configuration parameter while maintaining the current internal setting, use the **MANUAL** keyword with the **UPDATE DATABASE CONFIGURATION** command.

Is there a resource online that will tell me the values that AUTOCONFIGURE based on my current database manager configurations (assuming that I have not modified anything related to memory)? I want to know if not setting certain memory-related configurations will affect the performance of my database. For example, if I don't set configurations like pckcachesz to automatic, what is the default value of it?

Comment: Have you considered using `APPLY NONE` to see what it will recommend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start by creating the database without using `AUTOCONFIGURE`. Once it is created use `AUTOCONFIGURE` with the option `APPLY NONE`. It will show you what DB2 thinks are better settings.

Many DBAs then use the output of `APPLY NONE` as input to manually setting the values using `update db cfg`, it is a common approach.